# Cabal always out of memory

Tags: haskell

When I try to use the version of cabal from the repositories every command gives an out of memory error.

```
$ cabal install hedis
cabal: out of memory (requested 2097152 bytes)
$ cabal update
Downloading the latest package list from hackage.haskell.org
cabal: out of memory (requested 2097152 bytes)
```

This is using the versions of cabal and GHC obtained by installing the haskell-platform package
(cabal version 1.16.0.2 and GHC version 7.6.3).

EDIT:

The results of running free is:

```
free -h
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          994M       647M       346M       356K       4.2M        59M
-/+ buffers/cache:       583M       410M
Swap:           0B         0B         0B
```

so it would appear not to be a problem with actually running an actual running out of RAM issue. The hardware is a DigitalOcean VPS.

Comment: How much RAM do you have? How much Swap? (Find out by typing `free`) What hardware are you using? you could always `strace` your command, and see where it is requesting 2,097,152 bytes, then look to see why it wants 2,097,152 bytes.

Comment: @waltinator I've updated the original post with the information.

Comment: @waltinator I have exactly the same message from a completely different porgram (a one I have written; it uses a lot memeory indeed). This exact number 2,097,152 might be simply 2G. An upper limit for allocating memory (set somewhere?)

Comment: Try creating some swap space, telling the system to use it and trying again. See `man swapon`.

Answer (score 1):

`-j1` flag from running out of memory.

```
$ cabal -j1 install hedis
```